# Force a layout to be a square

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a horizontal LinearLayout which contains seven children. (It's a calendar)

These children all have the same width, depending on screen size. This is easy to achieve.

The hard part to achieve is to force the children to equal their height to their width (I want to resemble Windows Phone Metro style)

I populate my LinearLayout programatically. Is there any way to fix the height so it equals its width?

EDIT: Here's the code I'm using.

```
public View createWeekView(final Calendar moving)
    {
        final LinearLayout weekView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.calendar_week, null);
        final LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0F);

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            weekView.addView(this.createDayView(moving), params);
            moving.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
        return weekView;
    }
```

Comment: override `onLayout()` method of Parent.

Comment: Use fixed Width and height instead of Match_parent and Wrap_content

Comment: If I use fixed width and height it will show weird on different screens.